# How do I get the Application Name from either SQL Server connection string or the IIS application name using C#?

Tags: c#, connection-string

How do I get the Application Name from an SQL Server connection string in the web.config file.

I want to use to log escalated error messages from a web application into the Windows Event Log.

Maybe there is a better way of doing this, ie using the IIS/Web application name?

Thanks

Mark

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What does the connection string look like?

[`DbConnectionStringBuilder`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dbconnectionstringbuilder.aspx) is good for parsing and inspecting connection-string values by key:

```
        DbConnectionStringBuilder db = new DbConnectionStringBuilder();
        db.ConnectionString = connectionString;
        Console.WriteLine(db["Application Name"]);
```

otherwise you can get various details from the http [server variables](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.servervariables.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

[SqlConnectionStringBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnectionstringbuilder.aspx) is also useful if you are using SQL Server:

```
SqlConnectionStringBuilder sc = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder(connectionString);
string applicationName = sc.ApplicationName;
```